# most simple data frame split in R

Tags: mysql, r

I have a ~900K rows in a data frame, i'd like to split this data frame into two (not equal) data frames so I can later write it into Mysql db (for some reason dbWriteTable won't write more than ~700K rows), the outcome should be two new data frames with different names

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: `df1 <- df[1:600000,]; df2 <- df[600001:nrow(df),]`?

Comment: Thanks @Jaap ! It works just fine for me.
 i'm new to R, unfortunately i'm trying to do some complex thing before going over the basics and it makes me ask these questions.. I'm also new to Stack, as you can see.